# Initialize nested template classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor

I have many template classes, which work in a arbitrary order together (share the same concept).

Supposing that I have:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
  T t_;
public:
  void call() {
    // Do something.
    t_.call();
  }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class B {
  T t_;
  U u_;
public:
  void call() {
    // Do something.
    t_.call();
    // Do something.
    u_.call();
  }
};

class C {
public:
  void call() {
    // Do something.
  }
};
```

And I have the following instantiated class:

```
using Foo = A<B<A<C>,C>>;
```

Lets assume, C need a special constructor (or initializer function) to work probably. Something I do only know at runtime.

```
struct C {
  void init(int);
  void call();
};
```

How can I initialize Foo probably? Or any other nested class combination?

My current workaround is to define C as:

```
template<typename I>
struct C {
  C() : var_(I::get())
  void call();
};
```

And create Foo inside a function:

```
int main()
{
  int i = 0;

  struct HelperC1 {
    static int get(bool set = false, int value = 0) {
      static int value_ = value;
      if (set) value_ = value;
      return value_;
    }
  } helperC1;

  struct HelperC2 {
    static int get(bool set = false, int value = 0) {
      static int value_ = value;
      if (set) value_ = value;
      return value_;
    }
  } helperC2;

  helperC1.get(true, i);
  helperC2.get(true, i+1);

  A<B<A<C<HelperC1>>,C<HelperC2>>> foo;   
  foo.call();

  return 0;
}
```

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fa0ec0da525e026)

You see, this workaround is not very handy. Another approach would be to call the first constructor of Foo with the arguments and redirect them to C but this is very bad for different class combinations like:

```
using Bar = A<B<A<C>,<B<B<A,C>,C>>>;
```

Question: How to initialize nested (template) classes with a runtime arguments (better/in a nicer, cleaner way)?

Comment: By "probably" do you mean "properly"?

Comment: Why not provide constructor to your class `A` and `B` (and potentially getter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example builds values for branching template types with move construction and forwarding helper functions.

The forwarding helpers wrap constructors, using type inference to avoid the need to specify each constructor with its complicated parameters.

In this example, the call() function dumps the parameter structure and values of an object's children.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class A {
    T t;
public:
    A(T&& t) : t{std::move(t)} {}
    void call() {
        std::cout << "A<";
        t.call();
        std::cout << ">";
    }
};
template <typename T>
inline A<T> mkA(T&& t) { return A<T>{std::forward<T>(t)}; }

template<typename T, typename U>
class B {
    T t;
    U u;
public:
    B(T&& t, U&& u) : t{std::move(t)}, u{std::move(u)} {}

    void call() {
        std::cout << "B<";
        t.call();
        std::cout << ",";
        u.call();
        std::cout << ">";
    }
};
template <typename T, typename U>
inline B<T,U> mkB(T&& t, U&& u) { 
    return B<T,U>{std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u)};
}

class C {
    int c;
public:
    C(int c) : c{c} {}
    void call() {
        std::cout << "C(" << c << ")";
    }
};

int main() {
    auto bar = mkA(mkB(mkA(C{1}), mkB(mkB(mkA(C{2}),C{3}), C{4})));
    bar.call();
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
A<B<A<C(1)>,B<B<A<C(2)>,C(3)>,C(4)>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use pointers and build `foo` with already constructed and initialized objects. ie:

**UNTESTED CODE**

```
template<typename T>
 class A {
  T* t_;

public:
  A(T* valptr) : t_(valptr){}
  ~A(){ delete t_ ; }

  void call() {
    // Do something.
    t_.call();
  }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class B {
  T* t_;
  U* u_;

public:
  B(T* val1ptr, U* val2ptr):t_(val1ptr), u_(val2ptr){}
  ~B(){delete val1ptr; delete val2ptr;}

  void call() {
    // Do something.
    t_->call();
    // Do something.
    u_->call();
  }
};

class C {
  private:
    int x_;
  public:
  C(int x):x_(x){}
  void call() {
    // Do something.
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
A<B<A<C>,C>> foo( new B<A<C>,C>(new A<C>(new C(3) ), new C(3) ) );
```

Comment: Why the pointers? You can obtain the same without them... further your classes are not RAII anymore... if you create a copy which goes out of scope,   the member pointer is deleted and the class is broken. It's better to use smart pointers instead.

Comment: @davidhigh Could you show how to obtain the same behaviour without pointers (or references). A virtual common parent would allow to get rid of templates but not pointers. For RAII proper copy constructors and assignment operators should be implemented. Implicitly sharing the member classes could  introduce other errors depending on the use case.